# Convert and compare string to int from database

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

apperently when created my database has been storing dates as a string `Start_Date varchar(15)` Since there are thousands of entries already I want to go back into my db table and convert the following format `11/30/2011` to the unix timestamp.

Not sure if I am on the right track but here is a php script that may do what I want:

```
$query="Select * from Template_Approved";
    $result=mysql_query($query)
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i=0;
    while($i<$num)
    {

    $date_string= mysql_result($result,$i,"Start_Date");

     $timestamp = strtotime($date_string);

    $query="UPDATE Template_Approved SET Start_Date=' $timestamp ' ";

    mysql_query($query);
    $i++;
    }
```

I obviously have to update the table field to be an int (not a varchar)

Comment: I can't see a question here; have you tried running the script? Does it do what you want?

Comment: I guess my question is based on the flow of my script will I be updating the correct rows with the correct data?

Comment: I suggest you create a new field in the database for the new format, tweak your script so it updates to that new field, run it, and see what happens.

Comment: I don't understand this question. why not use mysql [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, like this `UPDATE template_approved SET Start_Date = STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%m/%d/%Y');`

Comment: Thanks @silverfox that is what I was looking for. I didn't want to use a php script to do it but I wasn't sure how to do it in MySQL.

Comment: @silverfox Why not answer the question formally rather than in a comment? That way the OP can accept your correct answer.